# Populating a tableView based on user distance form venue Location in Swift+Parse

Tags: arrays, swift, parsing, tuples, tableview

I was wondering how you would go about making a tableView that is based on distance between User and a location. My current way of going about it is to load the PFObjects from Parse (includes 1. Venue Name, 2. Venue Image, 3. Venue Location) and then using the information from the PFObjects to make tuples based on [(Name), (Image), (Distance)]. The distance value is determined through finding the distance from current user location and venue location.

Afterwards I would sort the tuples out by distance ( distance < 10 would be 'near' , distance > 10 would be 'far'). After sorting out the 'near' tuples and 'far' tuples I would append these values into their specific arrays (e.g. nearNameLabel, nearImageLabel) and use these arrays to populate the table.

So far I have been having trouble with properly filling the data into their designated arrays due to concurrency issues (placing things in the right threads). I was wondering if there is a better way of going about this issue? Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Check out the Location Restraints section here https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html

Comment: the problem i have with location restraints is that for the 'far' array. I am hoping to have the distance be greater than 10 and lesser than 100. Currently I only know of the function that sets the maximum distance parameter.

Comment: You'll have to read up on the parse query docs to make sure but I think you can keep re-filtering the same query with your new constraints, alternatively you can filter your arrays locally.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using separate arrays you can design it in object level. Like create a class `Venue`,

```
class Venue: NSObject {

  var name : String?
  var location : CLLocation?
  var image : UIImage?
}
```

Load PFObjects as Venue in a single `venueArray`.

Then sort it with user location,

```
func sortArray(venueArray : Array<Venue>, myLocation : CLLocation) -> Array<Venue> {

    var sortedArray = sorted(venueArray) {
        (obj1, obj2) in

        // The downcast to Person is only needed if persons is an NSArray or a Swift Array of AnyObjects
        let v1 = obj1 as Venue
        let v2 = obj2 as Venue

        let distance1 = v1.location?.distanceFromLocation(myLocation)
        let distance2 = v2.location?.distanceFromLocation(myLocation)

        return distance1 < distance2
    }

    return sortedArray
}
```